# Saying Kaddish for a Talmid chacham/rebbe muvhak

Tags: halacha, kaddish, yoreh-deah, rebbe-talmid-muvhak, talmidei-chakhamim

Is there a particular interest, either by Halacha or minhag, for Jews to   recite the mourner’s Kaddish for a Talmid chacham, especially their rebbe Muvhak?  My understanding is it is permitted to have a non relative say Kaddish for the deceased, but is there any priority for doing this to Torah scholars and teachers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bais Lechem Yehuda [YD 376:5](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8067&st=&pgnum=204) says in the name of the Rama that a talmid muvhak can say Kaddish for his Rebbi. Here is a picture of the line, since it is in the middle of a long piece and hard to find[image]

Comment: Did anyone suggest it was forbidden that we need a source saying one "can" do this?

Comment: Obviously the Rama is suggesting it. I don’t think he would go out of his way to say one can do it, if he felt anyone can do it at any time.